# How to test how long a client can hold an HTTPS connection open?

Tags: c#, testing, https, webrequest

I am developing against an API whose documentation says that the client code must be able to hold an HTTPS connection open for up to 15 seconds

I would like to be able to confirm this criterion programatically, preferably by having an integration test that runs on every build and holds the connection open for 15sec before passing. (Unless C# WebRequests guarantee somewhere that they will be able to hold the connection open for that long)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This a 2 way thing; the server has to support it and the client probably needs to set some sort of KeepAlive flag. [See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive.aspx)

That example sets KeepAlive to false; you'd want it set to `true.`

Excerpt from MSDN:

> When using HTTP/1.1, Keep-Alive is on by default. Setting KeepAlive to
>   false may result in sending a Connection: Close header to the server.